# How to correctly manage a bidding system with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I've developed a bidding system with PHP and MySQL.
It works good in the most of the cases, but I've noticed there is a problem when offers are really close.

```
$now = DateTime::createFromFormat('U.u', microtime(true));
$dateMicroTime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s").".".$now->format("u");
$amountToRaise = 100;
$lastOffer = $bid->lastOffer();
//if there is an offer yet
if($lastOffer){
    $newPrice = $lastOffer->getAmount()+$amountToRaise;
//else is the first offer
}else{
    $newPrice = $amountToRaise;
}
//if the user is not the last bidder
if($user->getId() != $lastOffer->getUserId()){
    $bidOffer = new BidOffer();
    $bidOffer->setBidId($bid->getId());
    $bidOffer->setUserId($user->getId());
    $bidOffer->setAmount($newPrice);
    $bidOffer->setTime($dateMicroTime);
    $bidOffer->save();
    //if this is not the first offer I give back the money to the previous user
    if($lastOffer){
        $lastUser = $lastOffer->user();
        $lastUser->setCash($lastUser->getCash()+$lastOffer->getAmount());
        $lastUser->save();
    }
}
```

The code works well when offers are done in different moments, but users offer in the same seconds for example: 18:00:01.1299022 and 18:00.02.1222377
The user with previous offer doesn't receive back the offer.
How can I fix this? I've tried to use a temporary variable to block the statement temporary until every query are executed, but no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would separate dateTime from microtime and would not use `$dateMicroTime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s").".".$now->format("u");`.

You can than use microtime to extract the last bidder. This can be done by adding a bid_utime column in your DB. If you are looking all the bidders for one auction chronologically `ORDER BY table.bid_utime DESC`.Last bidder can be found by `ORDER BY table.bid_utime DESC LIMIT 1` as a return from `$lastOffer = $bid->lastOffer();`.

This also means you wont be saving your bids with: `$bidOffer->setTime($dateMicroTime);`but with something like:
`$bidOffer->setDate($date);` and `$bidOffer->set_uTime($now);`

But you can also skip all of this and return only the last entry from the bid table with `SELECT * FROM bid_Table ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1` and forget about dateMicroTime and microtime. Hope this helps.